# PHP PDO placeholders will not DELETE

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have tried to delete a record in table 'telefoonnummers'.
But nothing changes. What is the error below?

```
<HTML>
  <?php
        require_once 'db_config.php';

        //get data last page
            $indexnr = $_GET['id'];

            $sth = $dbh->prepare("DELETE FROM telefoonnummers WHERE index = :indexnr");
            $sth->bindValue(':indexnr', $indexnr, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $count = $sth->execute();

            if($count == 1) {
        print "One record deleted!<br>";
            }
            else 
            {
        print "None record deleted!";
            }
        //Back to first page
?>
        <a href="admin.php">Back</a>
</HTML>
```

Comment: The code looks okay. Did you check the changes in the database directly? Do you have error reporting turned on for your code ? What is the output that you are getting from your current code?

Comment: Are you sure you are getting correct value for `$indexnr` variable ?

Comment: Try `$indexnr = (int)$_GET['id'];` maybe ? I am not entirely sure about this though.

Comment: done any basic debugging, like checking if the db stuff even ran? Unless you explicitly enable exceptions, PDO just returns false on failure.

Comment: the $_GET['id'] works fine, I can echo it on the screen.

Comment: Basic debugging: the db is working ok, I can display the records whitch are now in the table,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some basic debugging seems to be in order here -- check to see if the query worked. I don't see anything obviously wrong with your code.

```
try {
    $count = $sth->execute();
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    // do error handling
    var_dump($e); // use only for debug
}
```

`echo $_GET['id'];`to verify that you're pulling the the right information from `GET`.

`echo $count;`to verify that you're making a proper comparison.

Either way, it's good practice to have your critical PDO queries wrapped in a try/catch.

Comment: Good advice. To have PDO throw exceptions for debugging, we also need `$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`  (The recommendation in this answer will reveal a SQL syntax error, caused by a reserved word used as a bare reference to column. A couple of workarounds to that; my preference is to qualify the column reference with a table alias or table name, `WHERE telefoonnummers.index =`.  The other popular workaround is to enclose the identifier in backticks.

Answer (score 0):

```
object(PDOException)#3 (8) { ["message":protected]=> string(213) "SQLSTATE[42000]: 
Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'index = '4'' at line 1" 

["string":"Exception":private]=> string(0) "" ["code":protected]=> string(5) "42000" ["file":protected]=> string(50) "C:\USBwebserver\root\PhpProjectWeek5\verwijder.php" ["line":protected]=> int(14) ["trace":"Exception":private]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(6) { ["file"]=> string(50) 
"C:\USBwebserver\root\PhpProjectWeek5\verwijder.php" ["line"]=> int(14) ["function"]=> string(7) "execute" ["class"]=> string(12) "PDOStatement" ["type"]=> string(2) "->" ["args"]=> array(0) { } } } ["previous":"Exception":private]=> NULL ["errorInfo"]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(5) "42000" [1]=> int(1064) [2]=> string(157) "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'index = '4'' at line 1" } }
```

> Notice: Undefined variable: count in C:\USBwebserver\root\PhpProjectWeek5\verwijder.php on line 21
>       None record deleted! Back

Comment: I'm glad to see that you found the answer. If my post helped you, feel free to accept the answer and/or upvote it.